# custom handler for webform?

Tags: webforms

I'm not sure how to go about this...
Given a simple registration form that has three fields

- email
- country
- optIn (*conditional*)

When this form is presented, I'd like the Opt-in field to be hidden unless a specific country is specified.

Easy, so far. Just specify a condition for the Opt-in field set to `country` being a specific value.

Here is the catch:

Instead of the country being a static single (or multiple hardcoded values), I'd like to check against a list of countries already defined (in config).

Seems I will need to write a custom handler/plugin of this, but not sure which one to use as a base, or - if that is even the right approach.
Obviously, I'd like to retain the ajax behavior of the opt-in field appear / not appear dynamically when the address field is filled in (e.g., I don't want to have to wait for a form submit)
In the example below, I've arbitrarily configured US to be a triggered country and Finland is not

[image]